# Uniqueness of extension of signed measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, signed-measures

By Caratheordory's extension theorem, if the measure space is $\sigma-$ finite and we have two measures that are equal on an algebra generating the $\sigma-$ algbera, then they are equal. Will the same still hold if I consider signed measures instead of usual (positive) measures?